# Android: gravity attribute on item drawable

Tags: android

I want to achieve this kind of style

[image: image1]

As you can see, my background app is a texture so i need a transparent background and just a few pixels of gradient color at the bottom of the view.

I used simply this to describe my background of EditText

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">>
     <item
         android:gravity="bottom"
         android:height="2dp"
         android:drawable="@drawable/my_gradient">
     </item> 
</layer-list>
```

It works well on Android 6.0 and Android M Preview but not on "older version" as Android 5.1.1

API 23 and 22(M) versus API 22 and older rendering
[image: image2]

I can't understand why my gravity attribute is not applied

Comment: I would achieve this behaviour by setting the bottom line as a view in each layout separately.

Comment: I know but for robust code i do not want to use additional views to define an element of graphical design

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the gravity (and size) property for `LayerDrawable` children are recent, [LayerDrawable.setLayerGravity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setLayerGravity%28int,%20int%29) indicates
*Added in API level 23*.

Edit : As for a solution, here is what I could think of:

- Use a nine patch as background, with a transparent vertically extensible part
- Overlay the unwanted part of the gradient with another shape, having the same color as the background (wich obviously needs to be opaque)

  ```
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item
          android:drawable="@drawable/my_gradient" />

      <item android:bottom="2dp">
          <shape>
              <solid android:color="background color" />
          </shape>
      </item>
  </layer-list>
  ```
- Use a `View` to hold the gradient. Depending on how the `EditText`, is used in the layout it *may* be necessary to add also a `Framelayout`, for example :

  ```
  <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="2dp"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom"
          android:background="@drawable/my_gradient" />

      <EditText
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Some text" />
  </FrameLayout>
  ```

Comment: Indeed. Do you know how can i achieve this with clean code ? It's not an advanced need, i think it is possible other way and a good way :)

Comment: Added some suggestions, nothing perfect unfortunately